# XAML forcing autogeneratingcolumn to use custom datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, datagrid

Background: Working on a project with alot of data, creating an analyzing tool.

Problem: DataGridTemplateColumn does not support Binding. I need to create alot of datagrid's using the same template, but with different binding.

```
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="designData" 
                        ObjectType="{x:Type data:designData}"
                        MethodName="getVenstreOversiktSkuff"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cv" Source="{StaticResource designData}"/>


    <UserControl x:Key="ucContentForDataContext">
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="Kassett"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding KassettNr}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Varenr}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Varenavn}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate01">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass01}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate02">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass02}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate03">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass03}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate04">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass04}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate05">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass05}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate06">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass06}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate07">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass07}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate08">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass08}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate09">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass09}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate10" >
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass10}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate11">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ucContentForDataContext}" DataContext="{Binding Plass11}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cv}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate01}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate02}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate03}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate04}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate05}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate06}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate07}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate08}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate09}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate10}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate11}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Visual Studio:
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUzbN.png)

Running App:
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9X1x.png)

How come the datatemplates are shown in DesignMode in Visual Studio, but not when i launch the app with the exact same datasource.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the `DataGridTemplateColumn` *does not belong* to the visual tree. So the StaticResource markup cannot retrieve the resources which you declared in the UserControl Resource Dictionary, since there is no "connection" between the DataGridTemplateColumn and your UserControl.

Probably you can consider creating the DataTemplate by using code.
Take a look here.

**Xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="designData" 
                        ObjectType="{x:Type data:DesignData}"
                        MethodName="GetVenstreOversiktSkuff"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cv" Source="{StaticResource designData}"/>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DataGrid x:Name="dg2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cv}}" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
              AutoGeneratingColumn="dg2_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
</UserControl>
```

**Codebehind**:

```
private void dg2_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridTemplateColumn dataGridTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

    FrameworkElementFactory fefTextBlock1
        = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    fefTextBlock1.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Kassett");

    FrameworkElementFactory fefTextBlock2
        = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    fefTextBlock2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("KassettNr"));

    FrameworkElementFactory fefTextBlock3
        = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    fefTextBlock3.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Varenr"));

    FrameworkElementFactory fefTextBlock4
        = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    fefTextBlock4.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Varenavn"));

    FrameworkElementFactory fefStackPanel
        = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel), "stackPanel");

    fefStackPanel.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty,
        new Binding(e.PropertyName));
    fefStackPanel.SetValue(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, new Thickness(5));
    fefStackPanel.AppendChild(fefTextBlock1);
    fefStackPanel.AppendChild(fefTextBlock2);
    fefStackPanel.AppendChild(fefTextBlock3);
    fefStackPanel.AppendChild(fefTextBlock4);

    dataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    dataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate.VisualTree = fefStackPanel;
    dataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate.Seal();

    e.Column = dataGridTemplateColumn;
}
```

I hope it can help you.